# Error Compiling LibreOffice-6.0.7 on Ubuntu-18.04

Tags: linux, build, gnu-make, libreoffice

I'm trying to build `libreoffice-6.0.7` from source. After running make, some files were downloaded. Then the following command executed:

```
make -j 8 -rs -f /home/ahmad/libreoffice-6.0.7/Makefile.gbuild all
```

This led to the following error:

```
/home/ahmad/libreoffice-6.0.7/connectivity/Library_postgresql-sdbc-impl.mk:45: *** gb_LinkTarget_use_external: unknown external: openssl. Stop.
```

Does anybody know how to resolve the issue? Any help is appreciated!

---

P.S.: Note that the question is also asked [here](http://document-foundation-mail-archive.969070.n3.nabble.com/Error-Compiling-Libreoffice-6-0-7-td4301723.html).

Comment: ? Why the old version 6.0.7 which you can also install with apt.  (Released November 5, 2018.) Current is version 7.0.6 / 7.1.4 https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/

Comment: 6.0.7 build rules are https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic-updates/libreoffice → → http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice_6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10.debian.tar.xz

Comment: @KnudLarsen The source-based and the package-based versions need to match.